# sailsjs passing parameters to regular route

Tags: node.js, parameters, sails.js

I have read the documentation about Controllers to generate response in actions. But I am having questions about some other non-controller views. 
In the config/views,

```
'/':{view:'homepage'}
```

I am wondering, if I want to pass in parameters in to the homepage template, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass variables into your template by setting `locals` in the route config:

```
'GET /': {
  view: 'homepage',
  locals: {
    username: 'foo',
    email: 'foo@bar.com',
    ...etc...
  }
}
```

This is equivalent to the following in a controller:

```
res.view('homepage', {username: 'foo', email: 'foo@bar.com'});
```